# How to manage function when use concurrent in livecode?

Tags: scope, livecode

I have two graphics. These graphics have countdown function. When open card these graphics are start countdown. When countdown reach 0 these graphics are call function "refresh". These graphic are call function in same time. How to manage it?

Here my code on card for graphic use function:

```
on refresh
  if eCount is not empty then
    add 1 to eCount
  else
    put 0 into eCount
  end if
  wait 300 milliseconds with messages
  if eCount >= 2 then
    --dosomething()
    put empty into eCount
  end if
end refresh
```

Update ---

```
local eCount

on refresh
  add 1 to eCount

  if eCount >= 2 then
    --dosomething()
    put 0 into eCount
  else if eCount = 1 then
    --dosomethingOnce()
    put 0 into eCount
  end if
end refresh
```

When two graphics have call function "refresh" in same time. It's call method "--dosomethingOnce()". How do I fix?

And here my graphic code.

```
on countDown countT
   if countT > 0 then
     send "countDown countT" to me in 1 secs
   else
     send "refresh" to card "Main"
   end if
end countDown
```

Comment: I don't see any references to graphics in your code. Please, include the script that calls the refresh command and explain what you want it to do. Note that commands start with "on" or "command", while functions start with "function". Your handler is not a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another idea that I think may solve your problem (if I understand correctly!)

```
local eCount, sPending

on refresh
  add 1 to eCount
  if not sPending then
    put true into sPending
    send "doSomething" to me in 100 millisecs
  end if
end refresh

on doSomething
  if eCount = 1 then
    -- execute code for 1 timer
  else
    -- execute code for more than 1 timer
  end if

  -- reset flag
  put false into sPending
  put 0 into eCount
end doSomething
```

If the two timers finish within 100 millisecs of each other then the code for multiple timers will execute - otherwise the code for 1 timer will execute.  Adjust the 100 millisec setting to whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want something to happen only when both of the timers have called the refresh function.  Try the following ..

```
local eCount

on refresh
  add 1 to eCount


  if eCount >= 2 then
    --dosomething()
    put 0 into eCount
  end if
end refresh
```

by declaring eCount as a script local variable, before the handler, it will retain it's value.  When refresh is called the second time, the 'do something' code should execute.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I try follow this code and working fine. But I have some problem. If my graphic use function "refresh" in same time. It's working fine. But when it use function "refresh" not same time. How to manage it? I have updated in my question for manage when graphics use function "refresh" not same time.

Comment: I think I understand what you need - I've added another answer - hopefully it will solve the problem